# wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, webrat

I'm writing some tests in webrat with sinatra, and as part of that I need sessions.

The [webrat wiki](https://github.com/brynary/webrat/wiki/sinatra) mentions that I need to call `use Rack::Session::Cookie` instead of `enable :sessions` - I have done this.

This particular test looks like this:

```
class RegisterNewUserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Webrat::Methods
  include Webrat::Matchers
  include Webrat::Session


  def app
    Rack::Builder.parse_file('config.ru').first
  end

  def register_new_user
    visit '/signup' 
    fill_in "user[email]", :with => "testing@jamesrgifford.com"
    set_hidden_field "user[password]", :to => "password"
    set_hidden_field "user[password_confirmation]", :to => "password"
    click_button "Register"
  end
end
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
        from test.rb:77:in `<class:RegisterNewUserTest>'
        from test.rb:74:in `<main>'
```

When I remove `Webrat::Session` it goes away, but then my test is useless.

Comment: You need to ask a question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to include a class, which is not possible in ruby. Try using an instance of it :). Looking at webrat spec:

```
rack_test_session = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(app))
```